# Error when trying to start expo - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to start my expo project with "expo start" but I'm getting the error:

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

I'm trying to start my project using windows OS.

I have tried using increase-memory-limit to increase the amount of memory but without success.

Comment: Look into these cases: you either have an infinity loop. or an infinitely recursive function. increasing memory size won't help. inspect the logic of your code.

Comment: Hi TimeTrax, you made me look closely to my code and then I found a wrong import in one of my JS files. Probably imported by VSCode when I was typing.

Thank you very much Sr.

Comment: you are very welcome.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the same error by increasing the memory from 4GB to 8GB.
but now I think even that is fully occupied.

So I am in the same error again.